# PHP 5.3 SimpleXML to array type casting issue

Tags: php, casting, simplexml, php-5.3

I am trying to perform count on SimpleXML Element. It si giving me different results on PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.2. My code looks like follows :

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<command action="foo"/>');
print_r(count((array)$xml->children()));`
```

On PHP 5.2 the above prints "1" and on PHP 5.3 it prints "0" :(
I know I can use `$xml->count` but that does not take ino account the root element of the XML.

Just wondering what might be wrong in type casting the SimpleXML to array in PHP 5.3

Comment: How about just `echo count($xml->children());`

Comment: There is no children, no matter which php-version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, [SimpleXMLElement::children()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) will always return a SimpleXMLElement instance according to the manual.

And it does according to var_dump.

But as command has no child, the returned object has no accessible attributes which yields to 0 [when casting to array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose
> elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
> names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are
> unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the
> variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the
> variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

Couldn't find anything about changed type casting to array for [5.2 to 5.3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.functions.php).

So this might (might) be a bug ...